# How can I sort an array of integers, integer-letter combos, and ranges in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting, underscore.js

I have a strange array that I need to sort in a certain way, and I'm not sure if it's doable without a lot of manual labor.

Consider the array: `[ '1a', '2a', '2aa', '5-6', '1', '2', '3', '20' , '7', '8']`

It's an array of strings. Sorted properly, it would look like:

`[ '1', '1a', '2', '2a', '2aa', '3', '5-6', '7', '8', '20' ]`

Think of it like an outline numbering system of sorts.

How can I sort in that order?

Here's a jsfiddle showing how a regular sort treats it with its default lexicographical behavior (it's actually pretty close to what it needs to be):

http://jsfiddle.net/qkE9m/

I am working in node.js and have underscore.js at my disposal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's my attempt at solving this problem. The code is pretty verbose right now, but I'm looking at how to shrink it and will update my answer as I go. This should solve the problem enough to get you moving though. I'll be posting my code as a node module, since that's your env.

The gist of it is that it breaks the items down into separate parts that can be individually sorted. It loops each of those arrays in parallel, and once it finds a mismatch it will run a basic sort comparison.

#### sorter.js

```
// regex patterns to determine how to "parse" an input item
var patterns = [
    /^([a-zA-Z]+)$/,                      // only letters
    /^(\d+)$/,                          // only contains an integer
    /^(\d+)\-\d+$/,                     // contains 2 integers separated by a hyphen
    /^(\d+)([a-z]+)?\-(\d+)([a-z]+)?$/, // contains a 2 integer/letter combos separated by a hyphen
    /^(\d+)([a-z]+)$/                   // contains an integer followed by letters
];

function itemComparator(item) {
    var len = patterns.length,
        matches, x, regex;

    for (x = 0; x < len; x++) {
        regex = patterns[x];
        if (regex.test(item)) {
            matches = item.match(regex).slice(1);
            if (/^\d+$/.test(matches[0])) {
                matches[0] = parseInt(matches[0], 10);
            }
            return matches;
        }
    }

    throw new Error("could not parse item for comparison: " + item);
}

module.exports = function (a, b) {
    var compA = itemComparator(a),
        compB = itemComparator(b),
        x, len, tmpA, tmpB, typeA, typeB; // tmp vars

    // find the largest size, so we don't miss anything
    len = Math.max(compA.length, compB.length);

    // loop each comp arr in parallel
    for (x = 0; x < len; x += 1) {
        // store for speed
        tmpA = compA[x];
        tmpB = compB[x];
        typeA = typeof tmpA;
        typeB = typeof tmpB;

        // if the elements are not equal
        if (tmpA !== tmpB) {
            // then do the comparison, and stop the loop
            if (typeA === typeB) {
                return tmpA < tmpB ? -1 : 1;
            } else if (typeA === "undefined") {
                return -1;
            } else if (typeB === "undefined") {
                return 1;
            } else if (typeA === "string") {
                return -1;
            } else if (typeB === "string") {
                return 1;
            } else {
                console.warn("unexpected condition for %s (%s) and %s (%s)", tmpA, typeA, tmpB, typeB);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

#### test.js

```
var sorter = require("./sorter"),
    arr = [
        '1a', 'aa', '2a', '2aa', '5-6', '1', '2', '3', 'DBA', 'bb',
        '20', '2b', '7', '8', '125a', '33a-35', 'ABC',
        '3aaa-4c', '3aaa-52d', 'AA', 'c', '5dd', 'aa'
    ];

console.log(arr.sort(sorter));

// [ 'AA',
//   'ABC',
//   'DBA',
//   'aa',
//   'aa',
//   'bb',
//   'c',
//   '1',
//   '1a',
//   '2',
//   '2a',
//   '2aa',
//   '2b',
//   '3',
//   '3aaa-4c',
//   '3aaa-52d',
//   '5-6',
//   '5dd',
//   '7',
//   '8',
//   '20',
//   '33a-35',
//   '125a' ]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a bunch. This is good stuff. I was able to "break" it by adding the string `20a` to the mix.  I think it's a problem with the 3rd regex. Should allow for any integer followed by any length of letters. Like `125, 125a, 125aa, 125aaa, 125b, 125bb` should all be valid (and in that order).

Comment: I changed that 3rd regex to: `/^(\d{1,9}[a-z]+)$/` and that seems to work (up to 9 digit ints). I'm also thinking I need to catch ranges like: `33a-35` or `3aaa-4c`

Comment: I solved my last problem of int/str combo ranges like `3aaa-52d` by adding another regex of: `/^(\d{1,9}[a-z]+)\-\d{1,9}[a-z]+$/`

Comment: I would just use `+` instead of `{1,9}`, much less verbose and accomplishes the same thing. Glad to hear you were able to extend this to your needs :)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm trying to now add in the ability to have just letters and have them sorted before anything else, so like: `A, AA, AAA, BB, BBB, CCCCC, 1, 1a, 2, 3, 4, 5dd` and I'm not having much luck. My basic regex is: `/^[A-Z]+/`  Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like you're starting to fight the typical sorting pattern for JS, I'll play around with it and see if I can come up with something.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Here's a pastie of what the code looks like now with my other tweaks: http://pastie.org/5190814

Comment: Ok, I'm updating my example above to account for letters only as well. (it groups the uppercase letters before the lowercase letters, it can probably be improved upon with some sort of natural sorting algorithm)

Comment: Thanks Dominic. Simple enough to make the letters come before the numbers though? eg: `A, AA, B, BBB, CC, 1, 2, 3, 3a, 4`

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot that part. Let me tinker some more.

Comment: Ok, just posted my last series of changes

Comment: Thanks again Dominic! - It's sooo close, you got the `A` before `1` part right, however `1a` should come after `1`. So letters alone are before numbers in general, but number/letter combos are after the basic number.

Comment: Done, that will be my last change :)

Comment: And it's perfect :) - Thanks so so much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your actual data looks like, but this should nudge you in the right direction, I think:

```
[ '1a', '2a', '2aa', '5-6', '1', '2', '3', '20' , '7', '8'].sort(function(a,b)
{
    if (parseFloat(a) !== parseFloat(b))
    {
        return parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b);
    }
    if (a.charAt(0) !== b.charAt(0))
    {//just to be on the safe side
        return +(a[0]) - +(b[0]);
    }
    return a.length - b.length;
});
//result:
["1", "1a", "2", "2a", "2aa", "3", "5-6", "7", "8", "20"]
```

Comment: This is very close. The one thing that doesn't work, which is my fault for not including originally, are strings like: `2b` which should come after `2aa` in the above example.

Comment: I've added a new JSfiddle working with this as a basis. You can see some of the other strings that are possible. `2a, 2aa, 2b, 2bb, 2bbb, 2c, 2cc, 2ccc` would be a correct order.  http://jsfiddle.net/q6a4P/

Comment: @k00k: Are those strings HEX numbers? in which case you could just convert them to ints, sort those, and then we can all carry on with out lives ;-P

Comment: Ha, no, they're just strings that represent some weird page numbering scheme. I think I'm all good though based on what Dominic provided and my regex tweaks.